Din Rail Mountable Relay 18~20A 48V
Yesterday I was given the advice to use a relay instead of a pushbutton switch to apply 18A 48v to a circuit within my project. The relay is linked:
https://punchout.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cit-relay-and-switch/J107F1AS2048VDC-80/14001849?s=N4IgTCBcDaIFIEYAMB2AYggggZTEgLABwBqAIgMIB0hSIAugL5A
Even though this relay suits the job perfectly, it is not din rail applicable. A din rail appliable relay will work better regarding the previous circuit setup involving 6A 48V relays applied along a din rail. So I would prefer to find one that has available din rail mounts so I don't have to solder every relay and waste the current din rails. However, I cannot find any suitable relays that are din rail applicable on any main distributors (stated in the linked post). Any suggestions on relays any of you have worked with before? or would I just have to solder them due to the fact they cannot make suitable din rail mounts for 48V 18A relays I am not aware about.

There are Din rail boxes, boxes with PCBs, etc. that could house the relay. That is assuming heat, and other safety considerations. This isn't to suggest that there isn't suitable Din rail relays, just ways to use this relay on a Din rail.  Example: https://www.amazon.com/Distribution-Protection-Electronic-Transparent-Waterproof/dp/B0C3RB8WFK?source=ps-sl-shoppingads-lpcontext&ref_=fplfs&psc=1&smid=AJ274UC5EC51L

https://ph.rs-online.com/web/p/power-relays/2481766
